# Salesforce CPQ Approvals API: NullPointerException with no null arguments?

Tags: apex, api, approval-process, cpq

I'm a non-technical resource unfamiliar with Salesforce doing some urgent SF CPQ work. I've been trying to call this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.cpq_dev_api.meta/cpq_dev_api/cpq_api_aa_approve.htm via the API with the appropriate bearer token, but I get a

```
[
    {
        "errorCode": "APEX_ERROR",
        "message": "System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.\n\n(System Code)"
    }
]
```

error every time I try to post to the API with `SBAA.ApprovalRestApiProvider.Approve`. This only happens when the approvalID is valid. If it is invalid, I get the expected `Action can only be taken on approvals in Requested status` or similar. A sample body can be seen below. The Content-Type is specified as `application/json`

[image]

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here? I have been stalled by this for a week now.

Thank you

Comment: Could you share more context? What's the status of the Approval record? Are you just doing this through Postman/some API service? Or are you doing this through Apex? If so, what's the current state of the code?

Comment: Hello,

The status is valid, awaiting approval/rejection, I'm trying to send the approval request via postman right now to validate my approach

I haven't touched anything Apex code related as that is far out of my domain. I'm confused by it apparently working as expected if the ID is invalid/inactive, but erroring out like this with a valid one

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If anyone was curious, the SF Opportunity - Quote - Approval objects were misconfigured